# How to change position of ImageButton randomly every second?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I was wondering how I can change the position of an ImageButton every second. I want the position to be random each time. I do not know where to start to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you some idea

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="I am button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.com.randombutton;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random rand = new Random();
                while (true) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "thread");
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500), 0, 0);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    button.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            button.requestLayout(); //has to be called in UI thread
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. Make a thread, move a view and put it to sleep for 1 second. Probably there are better ways to move the view itself.

Comment: This actually worked very well but the only problem is the image is only moving up and down. It is not moving left and right at all. I believe it is because of the margins you have set but I am just making sure. How do I change this so it is moving all over the screen?

Comment: @ZainMerchant I tested it yesterday and it was moving also left and right. Try to set smaller range in margin and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just tried it and I still had the same problem.. Any other suggestions? Thanks for all the help.